# Sending the key pressed to the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AssociatedCard, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id="addCardBox", @onkeydown="test()"} })
```

Notice the `@onkeydown="test()"` attribute. This works fine, on keydown, a JS function is called.

But I want to send the key that was pressed, to the server, and save it to the database.

How can I send this key to the server, so that I can handle it in the C# code?

In asp.net, we can do something like this (which will allow me to bind to the TextBox):

```
<asp:TextBox id="txt" Runat="Server"></asp:TextBox>
```

At server side, I can then reach my textbox with the `id=txt`. Can I do something similar, without having to use ajax/JQuery?

Comment: Please show us the HTML that was generated from that `EditorFor` line of code. _`View Source` from the browser._

Comment: It would be helpful to see what test() is doing. 
Also side note: In your html attributes parameter, you only ever need the @ on 'class' and 'readonly'. That's because those are reserved words in C#. You should be able to remove it from your id and onkeydown.

Comment: test() is just doing an alert("Test"). This was to see if it registered the keypress. What test() is gonna contain, I guess depends on what's possible for me. It should/will contain ajax/jquery code that sends the key pressed to the server. But this is what I was wondering if I can avoid in some way? I will add the generated code for the EditFor, as you asked for  @mjwills

Comment: Is EditorFor producing a textbox?

Comment: Yes @Jacob it's producing a textbox

Comment: OK. See the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided EditorFor is producing a textbox you can do the following as it will capture the input.

You appear to be on the right track given that you've created a strongly typed view, you just need to wrap your inputs in a form to post them to the server.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostAction", "Home"))
{
    //Put your foreach loop in here
}
```

Then in your controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostAction(ViewModelType model)
    {
        //model.AssociatedCard should contain your value
    }
}
```